# Postgres truncates function names even though they are less than 63 characters

Tags: postgresql, function, truncate

I have this issue with the latest pg admin where postgres is automatically truncating function names less than 63 characters. I don't know if it's related to language or something else, but here's a function name I'm using:

"βρες_ασθενείς_μίας_μέρας_νοσηλευτή"

postgres truncates the name to:

"βρες_ασθενείς_μίας_μέρας_νοσηλευτ"

which is 33 characters.

Did the rules of max function name size change or is there something wrong with my preferences?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

["4.1.1. Identifiers and Key Words"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS):

> The system uses no more than `NAMEDATALEN-1` bytes of an identifier; longer names can be written in commands, but they will be truncated. By default, `NAMEDATALEN` is 64 so the maximum identifier length is 63 bytes. If this limit is problematic, it can be raised by changing the `NAMEDATALEN` constant in `src/include/pg_config_manual.h.`

Note that it says 63 **bytes**, not characters. If you use UTF-8, your untruncated string is 64 bytes long, which is too long. The  truncated string is 62 bytes long and fits.

Comment: And the src/include/pg_config_manual.h file is only found if I recompile the code? Because I can't find it on my local folder.

Comment: @MichaelEfraimidis: Yes, you'd have to change it in the source and compile yourself.